# Calling a parameterised method from another class

Tags: java

I have written a method in one class and wish to call it in another, i.e print the result.
Here is the method's class:

```
public class squareRoot {

    public double absoluteValue(double x){
        if (x < 0)
            x = -x;
        return(x);
    }

    public double squareRoot(double x){
        double epsilon  = .00001;
        double guess    = 1.0;

        while(absoluteValue(guess * guess - x) >= epsilon)
            guess = (x / guess + guess) / 2.0;
        return guess;
    }
}
```

The second class is a simple gui class and I wish to call the `squareRoot` method. I obtain the user input and then try to print the function, like this (with x being the user input in the gui class). However it is not working

```
 squareRoot(x);
```

Comment: Please give more details as to the manner in which it is not working.  Are you getting an error, a wrong calculation, compilation error etc?  Also please show how you are instantiating the squareRoot class and using it

Comment: @RobMcFeely I created an object of the squareRoot class, squareRoot obj;

Answer (score 3):

Declare your method as static

```
public static double squareRoot(double x)
```

and then call it by

```
System.out.println(squareRoot.squareRoot(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with static approaches, in more complex systems you'd have to think twice before declaring a static.

I recommend creating a instance for this purpose `squareRoot sqr = new squareRoot();`

You can then access the class method by e.g. `sqr.squareRoot(int value)`